# Gitlab — Failed To Register Shared Runner

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I have a private GitLab repository and admin access to it. Want to configure CI/CD. As per, https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/runners/ I try to register a shared runner. For this, I installed `gitlab-runner` locally and trying to register as per the steps described in docs.

```
gitlab-runner register
Please enter the gitlab-ci coordinator URL (e.g. https://gitlab.com/):
//As far as I use Gitlab CI, I enter default value: https://gitlab.com/
Please enter the gitlab-ci token for this runner:
//To grab the value for this one, I go to Settings -> CI/CD -> Runners and grab a token from right panel (e.g. one of the Enabled SHARED Runners token values)
Please enter the gitlab-ci description for this runner:
Please enter the gitlab-ci tags for this runner (comma separated):
//populate both with arbitrary data
```

After the last step I receive:

> ERROR: Registering runner... forbidden (check registration token) 
>   runner={runner access token} PANIC: Failed to register this runner. Perhaps you are
>   having network problems

I tried all shared runners access tokens, tried: https://ci.gitlab.com/ instead of the default one, but always get the same error.

Any insights much appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to register a shared runner. If you make your own runner, you register that. In your project, go to

Settings > CI/CD > Runners

The code you want in red on a pink background.